# HTTP/2 flow control in Node.js (grpc-js)

Tags: grpc, http2, flow-control, grpc-node

How is [HTTP/2 flow control](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#FlowControl) implemented in the Node.js version of gRPC (grpc-js)?

For the Go implementation (grpc-go), the logic is mainly in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/internal/transport/ (flowcontrol.go, bdp_estimator.go); also, it's described [here](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-go-perf-improvements/). However, I couldn't find anything for grpc-js.

I am mainly interested in when does a Node.js receiver send WINDOW_UPDATE frames.

Answer (score 0):

The grpc-js library is implemented using Node's http2 module, which handles the details of the HTTP/2 protocol, including flow control. So, there is no code in grpc-js that explicitly performs flow control operations. The http2 module, in turn, is implemeted using the nghttp2 library, so that code is where you will probably find the flow control logic.